# Which formula is correct for the variance of discrete uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76PIh08l5RY&t=210) offers this formula for the variance of discrete uniform distrubution:

[image: img]

However, this Wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) uses a different formula despite everything else is the same:

$$\textrm{var}(X) = \frac{(b−a+1)^2−1}{12}  = \frac{(b−a)(b−a+1)}{12}.$$

Can someone explain to me why we have this discrepancy?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your last step is wrong: $x^{2}-y^{2}=(x-y)(x+y)$ so you get the same answer in the two cases.

Comment: Those are the formulas from Wikipedia and an MIT video.  They agree on almost everything except that last part.  I do not think the variance is $x^{2}-y^{2}$.

Comment: @J.Doe There must be  typo. It is not true that $\frac{(b−a+1)^2−1}{12}  = \frac{(b−a)(b−a+1)}{12}$. Instead it should be  $\frac{(b−a+1)^2−1}{12}  = \frac{(b−a)(b−a+2)}{12}$.

Comment: Oh nice, thank you so much!